# Why isn't the parameter not passing as ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am trying to pass a ViewController as a parameter, but I keep getting this error. I am not sure why the error is occuring. Any help is appreciated. [image]

```
class Major: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

let initial = json.finddetailclass(self as ViewController, predicate: predicate)

 }

func finddetailclass(viewclass: Major, @noescape predicate: JSON -> Bool) -> JSON? {

    if predicate(self) {
        return self
    }
    else {
        if let subJSON = (dictionary?.map { $0.1 } ?? array) {
            for json in subJSON {

                if let foundJSON = json.findmultiple(viewclass as UIViewController //this is where I get the error, predicate: predicate) {
                    let shorten = foundJSON["html"].stringValue
                    print(shorten)

                }

            }


        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should downcast *self*. Try:

json.findmultiple(viewclass as UIViewController, predicate: predicate)

it's related to [Swift cast self in class func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432115/swift-cast-self-in-class-func)

Comment: Do i need to change anything in the `finddetailclass` function?

Comment: I thought the issue was with that class but it's with findmultiple class. Can you post the definition of that class too?

Comment: I edited the answer. You have to cast the value. There's probably better ways to do this using Protocols but I don't know what's your whole object relationships are.

Comment: I updated my code but these are the errors I am receiving. http://puu.sh/p4ahA/92ad46a1da.png http://puu.sh/p4aiE/0abd0a7a70.png

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna pass a ViewController as a parameter, using this type as its parameter type [AnyObject].

AnyObject likes a id in Objective-C. You can understand it is a any type of object of pointer.

func finddetailclass(viewclass: AnyObject, @noescape predicate: JSON -> Bool) -> JSON? 
......

And then , you can convert viewclass as real type of object while you're using this object.